# Simplest way to convert div to image HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I plan on converting a div into an image for a project I am working on. What is the simplest way of doing so? Ideally, I would not need to import any code.

I would like to make an image of this div

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<h1>This is the area I want to make into an image</h1>
<h3>I want to let the user download this div as an image</h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, for images, you would use an `<img>` tag but since you want to be able to download the image, then you can use an anchor tag with a 'download' attribute on it..

use an a 'anchor' tag with a 'download' attribute on it

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Just for clarification, divs are a completely separate HTML tag and should not be generalized.

Comment: I had this question resolved and I was trying to do something more fancy with divs. I would typically use img. Thank you for teaching me about the download tag though.